# Does Azure Devops allow me to import and edit an excel file on the Wiki board?

Tags: azure-devops

Currently we're using Azure DevOps -> Wiki to capture some requirements. We're wondering if we can import an excel file on Wiki and be able to edit right on the Wiki board (instead of downloading -> update -> upload).

Comment: annoyingly, it seems this is still something that is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

no, excel is not supported. [here's a wiki markdown reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/wiki-markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops). That seems to be pretty much all that is supported.

Answer (score 1):

better to use Wiki Tables.
the easiest way to copy Excel data to the Wiki table is to add "|" before, after, and in between:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you select the option of 'Paste as hml in the wiki editor', you can copy directly from an excel (online) and you will maintain frame as characters distribution. Hope this helps! :)